# Tensorflow: API recommendation for convolutional neural net?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have recently been looking into using TensorFlow for creating a custom CNN, and have been attempting to use the [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) for insight on the most straightforward way to design, train, and deploy an image classification network.

---

The two approaches that have stood out to me are:

[TF Layers API](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers): This API seems to provide the most straightforward and intuitive way of defining a network, layer by layer. That said, the way that they train and evaluate the model uses the `tf.learn.Estimator` class, which seems a bit limiting in that the network is strictly trained using the `Estimator`'s `fit()` method and validated using the `evaluate()` method. This tutorial does not even use a `tf.Session`.

[Low-level API](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros): Defining a network seems a bit more tedious. Also, training and deploying is done in a very manual fashion, but it appears to offer more control.

For a TensorFlow novice looking to implement and train relatively basic CNN's who is looking for the ability to tinker with network architecture and basic hyperparameter tuning, what would be the best API to get familiar with?

Also, if there are any useful tutorials or examples using your preferred interface, links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are _off-topic_ for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. This can be clearly observed by the variety of answers shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras is a nice frontend for Tensorflow. It sounds like it should fit your needs. Here is an [example](http://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-convolutional-neural-networks-keras-deep-learning-library/) of someone training a CNN with Keras.

Answer (score 1):

I like what is described on [this page](http://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/): write your stuff "by hand", but give the model a transparent class interface to the outside. TF graph stuff is handled as properties and set up at construction, and then the model can be used without having to know TF. A bit like Keras, but giving you full control (and forcing you to learn the low level). It lacks Keras' composability, though.

Basically, it recommends you do something along the lines of this:

```
class Model:
    @lazy_property
    def prediction(self):
        ...

    @lazy_property
    def optimize(self):
        # actual TF stuff here, e.g.:
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.target, tf.log(self.prediction))
        optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.03)
        return optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

    @lazy_property
    def error(self):
        ...
```

If it interests you, I tried to package up that approach with a common base class and decorators [here](https://github.com/phipsgabler/tf-models/blob/master/ffn_classifier.py). I tried to stick to the Keras API, and sessions are [explicitly handled](https://github.com/phipsgabler/tf-models/blob/master/examples.py) with `with`s. The code, however, has not actually been used in training -- I just wrote it after getting fed up with repeating everything in serveral university projects, and wanting to produce something cleaner.